# How to show current week dates from Sunday to Saturday

Tags: android

how to show current week dates start from sunday to saterday?im creating app which display current week dates when click on nextweek or previous week show next  or previous datesmy code display same dates on all 7 buttons

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static int mYear;

public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;

Button last_week;
Button next_week;
Button e00;
Button e01;
Button e02;
Button e03;
Button e04;
Button e05;
Button e06;

String completedate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e00 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e00);
    e01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e01);
    e02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e02);
    e03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e03);
    e04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e04);
    e05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e05);
    e06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e06);

//  e01 = Mon;
//  e02 = Tues;
//  e03 = Wed;
//  e04 = thur;
//  e05 = Fri;


    last_week = (Button) findViewById(R.id.last_week);
    next_week = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_week);


    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    completedate = mYear + "/" + String.format("%02d", mMonth)
            + "/" + String.format("%02d", mDay);

    last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            e00.setText("");
            e01.setText("");
            e02.setText("");
            e03.setText("");
            e04.setText("");
            e05.setText("");
            e06.setText("");

            }

    });
    next_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            e00.setText("");
            e01.setText("");
            e02.setText("");
            e03.setText("");
            e04.setText("");
            e05.setText("");
            e06.setText("");
            }


    });

   // i want to show like this

   //       e01.setText(" 9/9/2013");
  //        e02.setText("10/9/2013");
  //        e03.setText("11/9/2013");
   //       e04.setText("12/9/2013");
   //       e05.setText("13/9/2013");




    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(completedate);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

    String[] days = new String[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());

        e00.setText(days[0]);
        e01.setText(days[1]);
        e02.setText(days[2]);
        e03.setText(days[3]);
        e04.setText(days[4]);
        e05.setText(days[5]);
        e06.setText(days[6]);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

calendar.getTime() returns the current time. I think instead you will want to use:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

In this case -1 gives you one day before and +1 will give you one day in the future. So with this knowledge, you can keep track of the difference in time from today to the week you are displaying.

Does this make sense?

EDIT:

```
//positive numbers indicate future, negative past
int numberOfWeeksSinceTodaysDate = 0;
int dayOfTheWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Go back seven days
        numberOfWeeksSinceTodaysDate -= 7;
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, numberOfWeeksSinceTodaysDate)
        e00.setText(cal.getTime());     

        //Go back eight days
        numberOfWeeksSinceTodaysDate--;
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, numberOfWeeksSinceTodaysDate)
        e01.setText(cal.getTime());
        }

});
```

Comment: and how to print7 days in forloop?? dis function return same date in all 7 text

Comment: Give me a second, I am writing a better answer.

Comment: i want to print all seven dates in seven buttons

Comment: That is what the above code is doing. I just did it for two buttons because I believe that you can figure out the rest of the code on your own. Is there something that you are not understanding?

Comment: is not fixing where i place int values top of main method?

Comment: where u used this variable   dayOfTheWeek ??

Comment: is not working code is unexpectly clos e when click on button